# Background color from UIView is not changing

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a iOS swift app.
In a view Controller I am declaring a UIView :

```
@IBOutlet weak var task_color_view: UIView!
```

From another view controller I am getting a value for the variable color_cat:

I am checking the value for the variable and it is 9:

```
println ("COLOR CAT===")
println (color_cat)
```

Here is the console output:

```
COLOR CAT===
9
```

Then I try to change the background color from the UIView depending on the value of color_cat:

```
...
else if color_cat == "9" {
             self.task_color_view.backgroundColor == UIColor.cyanColor()
                                    println("ESTOY EN CAT_COLOR =9")
        }
...
```

The console is showing that the app detects that color_cat == "9" (then the output is shown as follows)

```
ESTOY EN CAT_COLOR =9
```

But the background color of the UIView  doesn't change to cyan.

Any help is welcome. What is wrong there....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.task_color_view.backgroundColor == UIColor.cyanColor()

This line has two equal signs in it; comparing equality. Change it to one equal sign so it will assign the value.

self.task_color_view.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()